# How do I change the value of a parameter inside Matlab's ode45 solver

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve a differential equation using `ode45` in Matlab. I'm running two scripts:

```
function xdot=linearproblem(t,x)

global kappa mass F 

xdot(1)=-(kappa/mass)*x(2)+(F/mass)*(cos(omega1*t));
xdot(2)=x(1);

xdot=xdot';

end
```

Then in the second script, I have

```
close all
clear
clc

global kappa mass F

kappa=4;
F=2;
mass=0.5;
options=odeset('omega1',[1.4 1.5 1.6]);

[t x]=ode45(@linearproblem,0:0.005:100,[0 0],options);
a=x(8000,2);

omega1=omega1'
a=a'
```

I'm trying to solve the equation using three values of `omega1`, but it's giving me an error:

```
Error using odeset (line 226)
Unrecognized property name 'omega1'.

Error in frequencysweep (line 12)
options=odeset('omega1',1.4);
```

I tried defining `omega1` as an argument: `function xdot=linearproblem(t,x,omega1)`, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no parameter called `omega1` in the help or documentation for [`odeset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html). That function is for setting the options for `ode45` (or the other ODE solvers), not for passing your own values into the integration function.

*And don't use global variables.* [There's no need in this case and most others.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/share-data-between-workspaces.html) Instead use an anonymous function to pass the parameters:

```
@(t,x)linearproblem(t,x,kappa,mass,F)
```

and make sure the `linearproblem` function itself also takes those parameters as inputs. Maybe `omega1` should be passed the same way:

```
@(t,x)linearproblem(t,x,omega1,kappa,mass,F)
```

(However, you'll get an error as the first `ydot` equation right-hand-side will be a vector, but `xdot(1)` is a single element – maybe pass `omega1(i)` and use a `for` loop around your calls to `ode45`?)

Comment: Thanks. yup i used a loop to store omega 1 values in a file and then solved the ode. It worked well.

Comment: @user3014799: Did my answer help solve your problem? If it was helpful, please accept it. Thank you.